# calculate the time difference between two dates in HH:MM format using ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, time, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, fetchxml

I need to generate the time difference between tow dates in SSRS in HH:MM format. How can i achieve this? My data source is MS CRM FetchXML.

Eg : Date1 : 01/01/2016 04:05 AM
     Date2 : 01/03/2016 02:15 PM
Time Differece Should be : 58:10

Regards,
Sandeep

Comment: Added ssrs-2012 tag as this seems to be what you are using - amend to something else if that is not the case.

Answer (score 3):

I might be a little too late but was needing to calculate the elapsed time between two times.  Hence I stumbled up this link

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/26d8b4fc-6862-42a0-ac7f-0caa93ba2fde/to-find-ellapse-time-in-ssrs-2008?forum=sqlreportingservices

The below expression worked for me. I also found it is simpler to do it in SSRS than SQL.

```
=Datediff("h",Fields!StartDate.value,Fields!EndDate.value) & ":" & Datediff("n",Fields!StartDate.value,Fields!EndDate.value) mod 60 & ":" & Datediff("s",Fields!StartDate.value,Fields!EndDate.value) mod 60
```

The result of the above will be HH:MM:SS

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=DateDiff(
DateInterval.Hour,CDATE("01/01/2016 04:05 AM"), CDATE("03/01/2016 02:15 PM")
) & ":" &
DateDiff(
DateInterval.Minute,CDATE("01/01/2016 04:05 AM"), CDATE("03/01/2016 02:15 PM")
) Mod 60
```

It will produce `58:10`

Replace CDATE() by the field or parameter containing your date time value.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom code to calculate time difference between two dates and return a string as expecting HH:MM like

```
    Public Function GetTimeDifference(ByVal dt1 AS DATETIME,ByVal dt2 AS DATETIME) AS String
    Dim Mn AS Integer=DateDiff("n",dt1,dt2)
    Dim HH AS Integer=Mn /60
    Dim MM AS Integer=Mn Mod 60
    Return HH.ToString() & ":" & MM.ToString()
    End Function
```

Now call this function as an expression like

```
=Code.GetTimeDifference(Parameters!startDate.Value,Parameters!endDate.Value)
```