# Summing up dd:hh:mm in ssrs expression

Tags: reporting-services, time, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

how can i sum up and find average of the following ticket age(shown in image). number of ticket=5 in this case. I want to show up the average of ticket age in a seperate cell below and should be in the same format(dd:hh:mm)

[image]

this fields is calculated expression:
s.TicketStatus = 'Closed' then
trim(abs((CAST(h.auditdate  AS DATE) - CAST(t.createdate AS DATE))))  || 'd:' || trim(abs((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM h.auditdate)) - abs(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM t.createdate )))) || 'h:' || trim(abs((EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM h.auditdate) - EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM t.createdate)))) || 'm' 
else 
trim(abs((CAST(current_timestamp  AS DATE) - CAST(t.createdate AS DATE)))) || 'd:' || trim(abs( (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM current_timestamp) - EXTRACT(HOUR FROM t.createdate )))) || 'h:' || trim(abs((EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM current_timestamp) - EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM t.createdate)))) || 'm' 
end as "Ticket Age"

auditdate: timestamp(3)
createdate: timestamp(3)
Thanks.

Comment: Is your TicketAge field a varchar or datetime data type?

Comment: this fields is calculated expression:

Comment: How are you calculating it? Share the expression.

Comment: please check the description : i added it there.

Comment: Why don't extract the seconds lapsed between auditdate and createdate then format seconds to d:hh:mm? Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36039681/2647648)

Comment: dint worked. any other idea